# Just when are unsafeVacuous, #., and .# unsafe?

Tags: haskell, traversal, fold

`unsafeVacuous` in `Data.Void.Unsafe` and `.#` and `#.` in `Data.Profunctor.Unsafe` both warn about the dangers of using those functions with functors/profunctors that are GADTs. Some dangerous examples are obvious:

```
data Foo a where
  P :: a -> Foo a
  Q :: Foo Void

instance Functor Foo where
  fmap f (P x) = P (f x)
  fmap f Q = P (f undefined)
```

Here, `unsafeVacuous Q` will produce a `Q` constructor with a bogus type.

This example isn't very troubling because it doesn't look even remotely like a sensible `Functor` instance. Are there examples that do? In particular, would it be possible to construct useful ones that obey the functor/profunctor laws when manipulated only using their public API, but break horribly in the face of these unsafe functions?

Comment: For the above `Foo` I think it's impossible to craft a law-abiding functor instance. I wonder which kinds of GADTs allow one to do so. It looks as if having a constructor `K :: ... -> Foo T` prevents any functor instance unless `T` is a type variable. (Maybe I am overlooking something, though...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there's any true functor where `unsafeVacuous` would cause a problem. But if you write a bad `Functor` you can make your own `unsafeCoerce`, which means it should to labeled with `{-# LANGUAGE Unsafe #-}`. There was [an issue about it in void](https://github.com/ekmett/void/issues/4).

Here's an `unsafeCoerce` I came up with

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies        #-}
import Data.Void
import Data.Void.Unsafe

type family F a b where
  F a Void = a
  F a b    = b

data Foo a b where
  Foo :: F a b -> Foo a b

instance Functor (Foo a) where
  fmap = undefined

unsafeCoerce :: forall a b. (F a b ~ b) => a -> b
unsafeCoerce a = (\(Foo b) -> b) $ (unsafeVacuous (Foo a :: Foo a Void) :: Foo a b)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ (unsafeCoerce 'a' :: Int)
```

which prints `97`.

Comment: It's possible to construct functors that cheat, for instance by having an `Fmap` constructor to fuse `fmap` applications, while hiding that at the module boundary. I'm mostly concerned about whether any such shenanigans could be mixed with a GADT in some subtly dangerous way.

Comment: Something like `data Fmap f a where Fmap :: (x -> a) -> f x -> Fmap f a`? That wouldn't cause any problems. It's only a problem when you specifically treat `Void` differently (like in my example). I don't expect someone could do it by mistake. As long as everything satisfies the functor laws it should be fine.